# How to query particular user in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
     UserId int,
     UserName nvarchar(15), 
     Permissions int
)

CREATE TABLE Permissions
(
     PermissionId int,
     Title NVARCHAR(15)
)
```

I have this `Permissions` table with this data:

```
Id  Title
--------------
1   'Read'
2   'Write'
4   'Update'
8   'Delete'
```

And `Users` table

```
Id  UserName    Permission
-----------------------------------
1   'David'     3
2   'Sara'      8
3   'Maryam'    15
```

in this case 'David' has 'Read' and 'Write' Access `(1+2=3)`, 'Sara' Sara Has only 'Delete'  Access`(8)` and 'Maryam' has 'Read', 'Write', 'Update' and 'Delete' Access`(1+2+4+8=15)`

How to know that David has 'Read' and 'Write' permission, or Sara has only 'Delete' permission?

Something like this, but in one query

```
with CTE as
(
     select a.Title, a.id + b.id as p_level
     from p a
     cross join p b
)
select u.*, p.*
from u u
inner join CTE p on u.permission = p.p_level 
where u.id = 1

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
with CTE as
(
select p.*, sum(id) over (order by id) as p_level
from p 
)
select u.*, p.*
from u 
inner join CTE p
on u.permission >= p.p_level WHERE u.id=1
END
```

Output (when `id = 1`): "David has Read and Write access" 1+2=3

```
1   DAvid   3   Read    3
1   DAvid   3   Write   3
```

Output (when `id = 2`): "Sara has only delete access" 8

```
2   Sara    8   Update  8
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the permissions using a `join`:

```
select u.userId, p.title
from users u join
     permissions p
     on (u.permission & p.id) > 0;
```

This puts the value in separate rows.

You can get them as a list using the trick:

```
select u.*,
       stuff( (select ',' + p.title
               from permissions p
               where (p.id & u.permission) > 0
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as permissions
from users u;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select  U.UserId , P.PermissionId 
From    #Users As U
Inner join
        #Permissions As P
On      P.PermissionId % U.Permisions >= 1
Where   U.Permisions - P.PermissionId > 0
```